# No response or no status Code on sending http requests other thatn GET

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I have created a rest API with Node.js (locally), tested all of end points with postman and all endpoints works.

I have created Angular app and trying to hit those endpoints with http requests. 
**Any http request other than GET is not working (I have tried POST,PATCH,DELETE ) and the same error.**

When I checked the *Network* tab on Chrome, the request was sent but no response and there is no request *Preview* or *Response* in the network tap

[image: request paylaod]

[image: request paylaod]

Here is the Angular method to send POST request and I have subscribed to it of course:

```js
addPost(post){
  return this.http.post<response>(`http://localhost:8080/posts/add-post`,
    JSON.stringify({
      title:"How to be Fit",
      content:"By Sports"
    }),{headers:{
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }})
}
```

I hope anyone can help me thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm since the backend is running in your local you can debug the function that gets executed when the post request is sent. You can check if the body is properly sent or not.

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but you don't need to stringify your body.

Comment: I tried using fetch Api the post request happens successfully but the recieved request body is empty at the backend I do not know why, then I tried the delete and the patch with the fetch api the above problem still happens. If anyone Can help me?

Answer (score 0):

the content type is application/json you don't need to stringify the request also remove the `<response>` .

```
addPost(post){
 // this http is the object of HttpClient(import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';)
  return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/posts/add-post`,
    {
      title:"How to be Fit",
      content:"By Sports"
    },{headers:{
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }})
}
```